# flutter map Instance of "configuration firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hello I am trying to get list of data but an instance of configurations is printed
it works with listview but I want it as listView.builder

here is my code :
`

```
 class Configurations {
      final List<dynamic> brands;
    
      Configurations({
        required this.brands,
      });
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            'brands': brands,
          };
    
      static Configurations fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Configurations(
            brands: json['brands'],
          );
    }

  Stream<List<Configurations>> readConfi() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Configurations')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => Configurations.fromJson(doc.data()))
            .toList());
  }

Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<List<Configurations>>(
            stream: readConfi(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<Configurations>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final brands = snapshot.data!;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: brands.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [Text("${brands[index]}")],
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ))
```

`
here is an image of data I want to get

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling `brands[index]`, this is returning the object of Configuration. If you want to get brands list use the following.

```
Text("${brands[index].brands}")
```

Or you can change the variable name from

```
final brands = snapshot.data!;
```

to

```
final configuration = snapshot.data!;
```

then use

```
Text("${configuration[index].brands}")
```

Furthermore if you want to iterate the list of brands.

```
Text("${configuration[index].brands.join(', ')}")
```

To show brands list

```
  return Column(
    children: [
      for(final b in configuration[index].brands)
        Text(b.toString()),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, but data shown like this [ Zara, p-side, Shien] how to remove these brackets and show them as list

Comment: Check last part of my answer, I have edited the answer.

Comment: thank you, it works. can it be done using a map? and how I can get the index of each value ?

Comment: Yes, it can be done by using map, configuration[index].brands.map((e)=>Text(e.toString()).toList().

Comment: To get the index you have to use the for loop, for(var i=0; i< configuration[index].brands.length; i++) Text(configuration[index].brands[i].toString()),